# mule mapping-exception-strategy only falls through to first 401 branch

Tags: mule, mule-studio

asking this for some mulesoft expertise.

the following exception mapping strategy is supposed to branch on hhtp.status 401, 403, 429 but keeps on falling into the 401 branch for status codes 401 and 403 (at least, and determined by both debugging and log written to console):

```
   <apikit:mapping-exception-strategy doc:name="waysact-adaptor-main-exception-strategy">
       <apikit:mapping statusCode="401">
           <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException"/>
           <logger message="psc&gt;&gt;&gt; logging 401 = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="log-http-401"/>
       </apikit:mapping>
       <apikit:mapping statusCode="403">
           <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException"/>
           <logger message="psc&gt;&gt;&gt; logging 403 = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="log-http-403"/>
       </apikit:mapping>
       <apikit:mapping statusCode="429">
           <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException"/>
           <logger message="psc&gt;&gt;&gt; logging 429 =  #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="log-http-429"/>
       </apikit:mapping>
       <apikit:mapping statusCode="400">
           <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException"/>
           <logger message="psc&gt;&gt;&gt; logging anything =  #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="logging-anything"/>
       </apikit:mapping>
   </apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>
```

is this because it is branching only on exception type org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException? i thought it was meant to branch on the status code?

there is another strategy, choice-exception-strategy, that should branch on different exception object types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branching of exception based on http.status can be defined with choice exception strategy as below example,

```
<choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
    <catch-exception-strategy  when="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.status'=='404']" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" >
    <logger message="Exceptions message is ... #[exception.message]" level="ERROR"  doc:name="exceptionLogger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="exceptionMessage" value="#[exception.message]" doc:name="Set exceptionMessage"/>
    <set-payload value="{  errors: {     errorCode: #[message.inboundProperties.'http.status'],     errorMessage: #[flowVars.exceptionMessage]  }  }" doc:name="Set Exception Payload"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
<catch-exception-strategy  doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" >
    <logger message="Exception message is ... #[exception.message]" level="ERROR" category="com.project.stacktrace" doc:name="exceptionLogger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="exceptionMessage" value="#[exception.message]" doc:name="Set exceptionMessage"/>
    <set-payload value="{  errors: {     errorCode: #[message.inboundProperties.'http.status'],     errorMessage: #[flowVars.exceptionMessage]  }  }" doc:name="Set Exception Payload"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: thank you, this looks promising; will investigate shortly

Answer (score 0):

APIkit matches the exception based on the exception value defined and not by the statusCode defined. Use choice exception strategy and define multiple catch exception strategy in it. Make sure each catch exception strategy matches a unique exception to make the way for proper http.status code and desired exception payload.

For example, if you want to have 400 to be thrown, make sure a catch exception strategy matches BadrequestException. If the status codes are coming out of the HTTP requester, match the ResponseValidatorException and set the incoming http.status and exception payload

Comment: thank you, am going to investigate w.r.t to both suggestions